# C# filter list using dynamic query library?

Tags: c#, dynamicquery

I am using a common function for filtering a list of records.

the function is below:

```
  class FilterRecords
{

    public static object ParseExpression(string Condition, string FilterColumn)
    {
        string _operator = "";
        string _condition = "";                       

        if (Condition.Substring(0, 1) == "<" || Condition.Substring(0, 1) == ">")
        {
            _operator = Condition.Substring(0, 1);

            if (Condition.Substring(1, 1) == "=")
            {
                _operator += "=";
                _condition = Condition.Substring(2);
            }
            else
            {
                _condition = Condition.Substring(1);
            }
            _operator = "=";
            return (dbContext.OrdsRlsds.AsQueryable().Where(FilterColumn + " " + _operator + " " + " @0", _condition).ToList());
        }
        else
        {
            if (Condition.Contains(','))
            {
                string[] conds = Condition.Split(',');
                return (dbContext.OrdsRlsds.AsQueryable().Where(FilterColumn + " >= @0 && " + FilterColumn + " <= @1", conds).ToList());

            }
            else
            {
                return (dbContext.OrdsRlsds.AsQueryable().Where(FilterColumn + " == @0", Condition).ToList());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This function uses dynamic query library. At the moment, it filters only one type of records - OrdsRlsds. I need to make this a generic filter so that I can pass any collection and then get the filtered results back.

Comment: try this topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7557761/apply-multiple-filtering-to-wpf-datagrid-using-c-sharp probably you can get some idea.

Comment: that question is asked by me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using Entity Framework? If so then could you do something like this with generics?

```
public static IList<T> ParseExpression<T>(string Condition, string FilterColumn) where T:class
{
  var query = dbContext
              .CreateObjectSet<T>()
              .AsQueryable();

  //add filters etc.

  return query.ToList();
}
```

You would then have to pass the required entity type as a type argument to your method like this:

```
FilterRecords.ParseExpression<OrdsRlsd>(condition, filterColumn);
```

Comment: Hi Tom, nice answer. I didnt get the last part of it "You would then have to pass the required entity type as a type argument to your method.". I appreciate your help. Thanks

Comment: Also Tom, I am having an observable collection on which I have to perform the filter. Can we pass this observable collection to this function and get back the new observable collection with the filtered records

Comment: I have updated my answer. I'm not sure how your second comment applies because I thought the data was coming from EF/a database?

Comment: Actually, its coming from the EF, but I wish to apply multiple filtering to the observablecollection which the datagrid is bound to. Is this possible in this method. Thanks Tom

Comment: Not sure I understand. Could you pass in an set/list of some new type which contains both condition and filterColumn? Then you could loop over and chain `.Where()` clauses on like `query = query.Where("a > b")`.

Comment: or you could have your method take the IQueryable<T> as its first argument and pass it through multiple calls to the same method, adding all your filters.